# Improving performance for sum and group by with large datasets

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a query that looked like this:

```
SELECT sum(score) as score, count(distinct(user_id)) number, round(sum(score)/count(distinct(user_id))) score_per_member, teams.*, types.name as type 
FROM `teams` inner join `users` on `teams`.`id` = `users`.`team_id` 
inner join `results` on `results`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
inner join `types` on `types`.`id` = `teams`.`type_id`
WHERE `results`.`year` = '2015'
GROUP BY `team_id`
ORDER BY `score` DESC;
```

Users has 250k rows. Results has 4m rows with 1m with year 2015.

Although explain doesn't look too bad:

```
1   SIMPLE  teams   ALL PRIMARY,teams_type_id_foreign   NULL    NULL    NULL    4449    Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  types   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   teams.type_id   1   
1   SIMPLE  users   ref PRIMARY,users_team_id_foreign   users_team_id_foreign   5   teams.id    57  Using where; Using index
1   SIMPLE  results ref user_id,results_year_user_id_index  results_year_user_id_index  6   const,users.id  6
```

It was taking 50 seconds to run.

I refactored it to:

```
SELECT score, number, round(score/number) score_per_member, teams.*, types.name as type FROM `teams`  
    inner join 
        (
            select sum(score) score, team_id, count(distinct(user_id)) number
            from `results` 
            join users on `results`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
            WHERE `year` = '2015' and year_id is not null
            GROUP BY `team_id`
    ) r on teams.id = r.team_id
    inner join `types` on `types`.`id` = `teams`.`type_id` ORDER BY `score` DESC;
```

Explain actually 'looks' much worse:

```
1   PRIMARY <derived2>  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2045    Using filesort
1   PRIMARY teams   eq_ref  PRIMARY,teams_type_id_foreign   PRIMARY 4   r.team_id   1   
1   PRIMARY types   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   teams.type_id   1   
2   DERIVED users   range   PRIMARY,users_team_id_foreign   users_team_id_foreign   5   NULL    132496  Using where; Using index
2   DERIVED results ref user_id,results_year_user_id_index  results_year_user_id_index  6   users.id    6
```

But the performance is now much, much better (2 seconds).

How could I improve queries like this even more? Is it just a case of throwing more hardware at it?

Comment: For the first query you could extend the `results_year_user_id_index` to be covering (I suppose adding the `score` column should be enough, but hard to say for sure without tables structure) - that would eliminate table accesses in the last step of the plan (around 1 million of random IO accesses by the estimates in the plan).

Comment: (that index might actually help even the second query) - are you sure the speedup was because of the rewrite and not because the first query loaded the data into the buffer pool and other caches? Did you try to run it multiple times?

Comment: Yes - I ran the query several times with SQL_NO_CACHE.

Comment: Yes, typo, sorry. Corrected now.

Comment: Did you try to add (append) the `score` column to `results_year_user_id_index`?

Answer (score 4):

The big issue is "inflation-deflation" when you do `JOIN` + `GROUP BY`.

Think of what `JOIN` does -- it generates an intermediate table with teams * types/team * users/type/team * results/...  That is, that table is much bigger than any of the original tables.

Then it does the `GROUP BY` do deflate that back to one row per team.

Usually the combination gives `COUNTs` and `SUMs` that are bigger than expected.  (Did you check?)  And it takes a long time.

So, the trick is to use subqueries to avoid any single query with both `JOIN` and `GROUP BY` in it.  (The combo is ok if the `JOIN` is known to be 1:1, which seems to be the case for `teams` and `types`, but not the other `JOINs`.)

There are two ways to do such subqueries:

```
SELECT
        ( SELECT SUM() FROM ... WHERE ... ) -- correlated subquery; single result only
    FROM ...
```

The subquery is effectively a `GROUP BY` without saying it, but it boils down to a single value, thereby avoiding the "inflation".

and

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ( SELECT COUNT(), SUM(...) FROM ... GROUP BY ...
         ) AS x  -- tmp table for some of the data; no JOIN
    JOIN ...
```

The subquery "deflates" some of the data before getting to the `JOIN`.

Caution:  Using multiple subqueries of the second kind is slow because of lack of indexes:

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ( SELECT ... ) a
    JOIN ( SELECT ... ) b ON ...
```

5.6 helps somewhat because it discovers and adds an index.

Comment: This was an excellent help for group by speed problem I had to resolved